# Bulk actions: what to do when not all items support an action

Tags: lists, multi-selection, selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bulk actions: what to do when not all items support an action](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/bulk-actions-what-to-do-when-not-all-items-support-an-action)

Picture the following scenario: user selects a bunch of items, and the 'bulk actions' box appears; user selects an action that not all items support (for one reason or another).

What do you do in this case: apply the action to items that support it? don't apply the action at all?

Also, can you point me towards any relevant real-world examples?